# exec-maven-plugin skip multiple conditions

Tags: java, maven, skip, exec-maven-plugin

I need to skip an execution when any of 2 conditions occurs.

Something like this:

```
mvn clean test -DconditionA=false -DconditionB=false
```

This is my example pom:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.6.0</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>list-dir</id>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>exec</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <executable>ls</executable>
                          <workingDirectory>.</workingDirectory>
                          <arguments>
                              <argument>-ls</argument>
                          </arguments>
                          <skip>${conditionA}</skip>
                          <skip>${conditionB}</skip>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

What I want is to be able to skip this execution wether conditionA or conditionB are true. Just second skip works as it overrides 1st one.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the [Maven antrun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)

Comment: Why do you need such a setup? Which kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a profile to overwrite `conditionA` when `conditionB` is set to true:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>conditionB</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <property>
      <conditionA>true</conditionA>
    </property>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This will work for:

```sh
mvn clean test -DconditionA=true
```

or:

```sh
mvn clean test -DconditionB=true
```

It might not work for:

```sh
mvn clean test -DconditionA=false -DconditionB=true
```

I haven't tried it. If it doesn't, and you actually need that, you'll need to add another property and profiles for both A and B that set it.